# Does Kafka Streams GlobalKTable topic require the same number of partitions as KStream topic which it will be joining with?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-partition

We want to use GlobalKTable in Kafka streams application. Input topics(KTable/KStream) have N partitions and a GlobalKTable will be used as a dictionary in the stream application.

Does the input topic for the GlobalKTable *must have the same number of partitions as other input topics* (which are sources of KTable/KStream)?

As I understand, the answer is NO(it is not limited and the topic may also have M partitions where N > M), because GlobalKTable is fully loaded in each instance of the stream application and the co-partitioning is not required during KStream join operation. But I need confirmation from the experts!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, The number of partitions for topics for KStream and GlobalTable (that are join) can differ.

From Kafka Streams developer guide

> At a high-level, KStream-GlobalKTable joins are very similar to KStream-KTable joins. However, global tables provide you with much more flexibility at the some expense when compared to partitioned tables:
>
> - **They do not require data co-partitioning.**

More details can be found here:

[Global Table join](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#kstream-globalktable-join)

[Join co-partitioning requirements](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#streams-developer-guide-dsl-joins-co-partitioning)

Answer (score 0):

***More accurately:***

> Why is data co-partitioning required? Because KStream-KStream,
> KTable-KTable, and KStream-KTable joins are performed based on the
> keys of records (e.g., leftRecord.key == rightRecord.key), it is
> required that the input streams/tables of a join are co-partitioned by
> key.
>
> The only exception are KStream-GlobalKTable joins. Here,
> co-partitioning is it not required because all partitions of the
> GlobalKTable‘s underlying changelog stream are made available to each
> KafkaStreams instance, i.e. each instance has a full copy of the
> changelog stream. Further, a KeyValueMapper allows for non-key based
> joins from the KStream to the GlobalKTable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My answer is clear enough i think .

Comment: (1) You should give the source for your citation. (2) You should add some *original* commentary/explanation as to the relevance of the citation.